# Direct Sum of Alternating k-tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", and I'm being tripped up by a statement made in passing on p. 30:

For a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, say of dimension n, define 
$$A_*(V) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k(V) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{n} A_k(V)$$

Here, I understand the $A_k(V)$ components to be the $k$-covectors on $V$, i.e. the set of all alternating $k$-linear functions from $V^k$ to the real numbers. What I don't understand is why the infinite direct sum of these vector spaces is equivalent to the finite direct sum truncated at $n$.

I imagine this has something to do with the dimension of $V$ itself. though I can't see why, for example, an alternating $(n+1)$-linear function would not be admissible here. I think it's likely that I'm not interpreting the notion of a direct sum of vector spaces correctly.

Comment: The only alternating $k$ linear function on an $n$ dimensional vector space, with $n < k$, is zero. (Exercise.)

Comment: @Lorenzo thank you, that makes sense, and is actually proven quite elegantly a few pages later in the text.

A follow-up question then: how is the direct sum meant to be interpreted? To be explicit, a typical element of $A_*(V)$ might look something like $a_{i_0} + ... + a_{i_n}$, with $a_{i_k} \in A_k(V)$, but I'm kind of unclear as to what it means to add two functions that have entirely different domains (i.e. $V$ vs $V \times V$ vs. etc.).

Comment: it's not necessarily possible to interpret the mixed tensors as functions. It's like the joke: what's an apple plus an orange? An element of the free vector space on apple, orange.

Comment: You can add them in a formal way by extending them by zero - so they'll become functions on the disjoint union of the products of the V. So you could think of it as a function that takes in a tuple of vectors, with no restrictions on the size of that tuple, and has the appropriate multilinearity.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt What do you think of my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's an error in the order of the material presented because your question is answered By Corollary 3.31 of the subsequent subsection (LOL).

[image]